# Pass array items as multiple params in jQuery AJAX POST

Tags: jquery

I have an array of id's which I wish to pass as a parameter to a webservice via jQuery's $.post like so:

```
var selections = [1,2,3,4];

$.post('/save', {ids: selections, function(data) {
    // do something
});
```

Unfortunately the code above submits multiple parameters (which is what I want) but it appends a '[]' to the parameters name so the params sent through when inspected with firebug look like:

```
ids[] 1
ids[] 2
ids[] 3
ids[] 4
```

The size of the array is dynamic so I can't hardcode it. Is there a dynamic way to do this **without creating a parameter string manually?**

Thanks,
  gearoid.

**EDIT:**

I should also mention that I'm submitting to a Jersey Webservice method which looks like the following:

```
@POST 
@Path("save")
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of dynamically creating a paremeter string using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/rre47/4/

```
var arr = {'ids' : []};//create new object (empty)
```

The basic idea is to create an object with an array under the 'ids' key. Then iterate through your data to append data to this array:

```
arr.ids.push(<some value>);
```

Then to output the parameter string:

```
decodeURIComponent($.param(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON encoding:

```
var selections = [1,2,3,4];
$.post('/save', {ids: selections}, function(data) {
    // do something
},
"json");
```

From [**jQuery's post**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

This would create a string: `'{"ids": [1,2,3,4]}'` and send that to the server.

And you seem to have a typo in your question:

```
$.post('/save', {ids: selections, function(data) {
```

should be:

```
$.post('/save', {ids: selections}, function(data) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the jQuery function `$.param()` is what you need:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 1):

Use traditional AKA "shallow" serialization as described here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/.

The result at the first "level" will be without the brackets.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/save',
    data : {
        ids: selections
    },
    traditional : true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use the Array method `.join` to create a string out of the array, and then use PHP's `explode` function to convert it back into an array:

JS:

```
var selectionsString = selections.join('|'); //returns '1|2|3|4'

$.post('/save', {ids: selectionsString, function(data) {
    // do something
});
```

PHP:

```
$selectionsArray = explode('|', $_POST['ids']); //returns [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Fine Gearoid. But surely there is a similar method for whatever you ARE using, or one could be created without too much trouble.

Comment: Of course, but you're also suggesting I put client specific code in my service layer. You're suggesting I write code in my API that handles different input formats which isn't the API's job. Assume that I'm not even allowed to touch the web service code.

Comment: Why should I assume these things? You never said them until now.

Comment: So you'd like me to write "Assume I want to keep my server side code loosely coupled from my client side?"